# ECDHE how the client sends Premaster sectret

Tags: ssl, networking, tls1.2

According to [RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-tls-rfc5246-bis-00#section-7.4.7) client sends premaster secret encrypted with RSA public key of the server. But when they are using ECDHE as asymmetric algorithm, client key exchange message will contain the pulic key of the client. If this is the case ? when will the client send premaster secret and how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when will the client send premaster secret and how ?

It won't. See #8.1.2:

> A conventional Diffie-Hellman computation is performed. The negotiated key(Z) is used as the  pre_master_secret.

Comment: ohhhh. missed that ... Thank you :)